# What is the best practice in connecting multiple databases in node.js using pg-promise;

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I'm using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) to build an API application. Based on the URL request provided, the application should connect to the desired database and provide the API accordingly. For example:

- localhost:3000/data/:organizationId#1/data ==> connect to database#1 ==>
  response with data#1
- localhost:3000/data/:organizationId#2/data ==> connect to
  database#2 ==> response with data#2

My understanding is that I need to have some kind of logic to connect to the desired database based on the URL, so I tried to change the connection string based on the passed request as shown in the code below.

Now, this setup works fine as a demo, but it is not practical since in the case of multiple requests, I reach the `max_connections` easily and I get the error message `sorry, too many clients already` till all the opened requests are closed.

Is there any better way to handle this issue? maybe to dynamically check whether a new connection is needed before actually connect (i.e. to avoid reaching the maximum connections)?

```
const config = require('config');
const squel = require('squel').useFlavour('postgres');
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();

function Model(koop) {}

Model.prototype.getData = function (req, callback) {

    if (req.organizationId === '1') {
        let db = pgp(config.db.postgis1); //connection based on organization Id #1
    }
    if (req.organizationId === '2') {
        let db = pgp(config.db.postgis2); //connection based on organization Id #2
    }
    db
        .query(formatSQL(req))
        .then(function (data) {
            // some function        
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            callback({
                'error': 'error running query',
                'error_details': err
            });
        })
        .finally(pgp.end());
}

function formatSQL(req) { 
//some function
}

module.exports = Model
```

Comment: How many databases have you got? Is that a static number? You should read about multi-tenant implementations.

Comment: @vitaly-t.. For now, 3 databases but more databases might be added in the future.

Comment: You can create a separate `Database` object, one for each database. They each will be using their own connection pool. A proper solution depends on the number of databases and how it will scale. You should read about multi-tenant solutions.

Comment: @vitaly-t I will. any recommended resource/tutorial on dealing with multi-tenant solutions and pg-promise?